# Некорректно работает JS код

Tags: javascript, html

Есть такой select:

```
<select name="priority_quick_jump_box" id="priority_quick_jump_box" form="add_rule_form">
   <option value="3">Низкий</option>
   <option value="4">Нормальный</option>
   <option value="5">Высокий</option>
   <option value="15">Не определен</option>
</select>
```

Также определена переменная:

```
var currPriority = "Высокий"
```

Есть некоторое событие, при возникновении которого значение `currPriority` (может быть не только "Высокий") устанавливается в `select` и делает эту строчку выбранной.
Вот такой JS код:

```
if (currPriority == "") {
    $("#priority_quick_jump_box [value='15']").attr("selected", "selected");
  } else {
    $("#priority_quick_jump_box option").each(function () {
      if ($(this).text().indexOf(currPriority.slice(1)) >= 0) {
        $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
      }
    });
  }
```

Не пойму с чем это связано, но иногда бывает так, что при значении `currPriority = "Высокий"` значение селекта не устанавливается, ставится первое, "Низкий"!, а иногда срабатывает. Может у кого есть идеи с чем это связано?
UPD:
Вот например, сейчас `currPriority = "Высокий"`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А после клика на строчку, "Высокий" не выбирается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Хотя в некоторых других строчках все в порядке. Причем происходит это только со словом "Выской"

Comment: почему здесь прямое сравнение: `alert(currPriority === $(this).text());`, а тут `currPriority == $(this).text().slice(1)` без первого символа? причем почему-то булевское значение сравнивается с числом

Comment: А какая версия JQuery? В новых версиях надо использовать prop вместо attr для установки select

Comment: @Grundy, код поправил

Comment: @Crantisz, jquery-1.7.1.min

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь селектором [`contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```js
var currPriority = "Высокий";

$('#setValue').on('click', function(e){
  // Если не очистить это свойство, то сработает только раз
  // Иначе после выбора пользователем другого значения, установка ничего не даст
  $('#priority_quick_jump_box option:selected').removeProp('selected');
  $(`#priority_quick_jump_box option:contains('${currPriority}')`).prop('selected', 'true');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="priority_quick_jump_box" id="priority_quick_jump_box" form="add_rule_form">
   <option value="3">Низкий</option>
   <option value="4">Нормальный</option>
   <option value="5">Высокий</option>
   <option value="15">Не определен</option>
</select><br />
<input type='button' id='setValue' value='Установить "Высокий"' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была проще, чем казалось. Добавив `currPriority.trim()` все заработало